# Setting map coordinate bounds defaults to showing (0, 0)

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm constructing a `MGLCoordinateBounds` that I want to show in an `MGLMapView`. Everything's fine until I try to use edge insets to provide some padding. Calling `setVisibleCoordinateBounds(_:, edgePadding:, animated:)` with edge insets of 100px on all sides is fine. If I set the edge insets to 200px on all sides though, the map view moves to (0, 0). I had expected that the map zoom factor would change to make everything fit. FWIW, on the iPhone 6 I'm using, the map view is 653x750 pixels, the insets aren't exceeding the map view size.

I could live with 100px padding, but what concerns me is that I don't know when or why this problem will crop up. Will some values of `MGLCoordinateBounds` have the same problem with 100px padding? Is there some way to predict and avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Deep down](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/1fa1819de1ffadc74c07972b7195cfdaea663507/platform/ios/src/MGLMapView.mm#L2278) the `MGLCoordinateBounds` is converted into a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.  All along the units are degrees.

Just to verify, you are converting `100px` and `200px` to degrees, correct?

Sorry for the obvious question.  The reset of the Mapview to (0, 0) is puzzling.

You may have to compute the padding in degrees based in Zoom level

---

A suggestion for padding, where some math is involved for `topBottom` and `leftRight`

```
    let topBottom = // computation based on Zoom level, and horizontal screen resolution
    let leftRight = // computation based on Zoom level, and vertical screen resolution
    let edgeOffset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top: topBottom, 
                                      left: leftRight, 
                                      bottom: topBottom, 
                                      right: leftRight)
```

Comment: I'm not converting the 100px and 200px measurements to degrees, because the method I'm using-- `setVisibleCoordinateBounds(_:, edgePadding:, animated:)`-- specifically uses `UIEdgeInsets` for padding. If I were converting to degrees I could use `setVisibleCoordinateBounds(_:,animated:)`, but it doesn't look like that should be necessary with the method I'm using.

Comment: EdgeInsets may not be implemented then.  The test code only tested Edges of zero.   Could you file a feature request or issue at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/

Comment: Tom, just ran across this answer.  Is it related to what you are looking for?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946722/how-to-zoom-mapbox-using-swift-to-a-given-radius-in-kilometers/38946880#38946880