# How to zoom Mapbox using Swift to a given radius in kilometers?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I recently updated from legacy Mapbox SDK (version 1.6) to latest Mapbox iOS SDK 3.x.

In new version I am not able to figure out how to zoom Mapbox MGLMapView to a given radius in kilometers to fit on screen.

In old (version 1.6) `RMMapView.zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest` method does the job as following:

```
func centerAndZoom(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, kilometers: Float) {
    let meters = Double(kilometers * 1000)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, meters / 2, meters / 2);

    let northEastLat = center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta / 2);
    let northEastLon = center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);
    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: northEastLat, longitude: northEastLon)

    let southEastLat = center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2);
    let southEastLon = center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);
    let southEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: southEastLat, longitude: southEastLon)

    self.mapView.zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest(southEast, northEast: northEast, animated: true)
}
```

How to achieve a radius zoom in latest Mapbox using Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now `-setVisibleCoordinateBounds:animated` will do the job:

> Changes the receiver’s viewport to fit the given coordinate bounds, optionally animating the change.

[Mapbox iOS SDK Reference](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.3.4/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)setVisibleCoordinateBounds:animated:)

Here is an example:

```
let bounds = MGLCoordinateBounds(
        sw: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.7115, longitude: 10.3725),
        ne: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.7318, longitude: 10.4222))
mapView.setVisibleCoordinateBounds(bounds, animated: false)
```

Comment: It could be real helpful, if u really could place there some real code like for situation described. ( i mean converting radius + centre --> MGLCoordinateBounds )

Comment: how is one supposed to know the sw and ne ? i have a reused screen showing 2 different annotations. but it's always different location degrees. do i need to calculate the sw/ne coordinates for the 2 given annotations?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I made zoom to specific radius from given coordinate:

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: <#T##CLLocationDegrees#>, longitude: <#T##CLLocationDegrees#>)
let kilometers: Double = 2.0
let halfMeters = (kilometers * 1000) / 2
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, halfMeters, halfMeters)
let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2),
    longitude: center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2)
)
let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2),
    longitude: center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2)
)

let bounds = MGLCoordinateBounds(sw: southWest, ne: northEast)
mapView.setVisibleCoordinateBounds(bounds, edgePadding: .zero, animated: false)
```